# Docker Spring Boot with MySQL database, connection refused

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I try to connect from my Spring Boot Container to a MySQL database but the connection breaks

This is my compose file.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapi:
    image: myapi:local
    container_name: myapi
    build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=5000
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/testdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admindev
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admindev
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_USER=admindev
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admindev
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

The MySQL container starts and it's waiting for connections.
The application also starts, but when it tries to connect to the DB it breaks.

I can't find anything wrong with the docker-compose file. I looked over the documentation and I saw that in the data source URL, I can even omit the port.

**UPDATE**

mysql container logs:

```
2021-03-05 13:20:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-03-05 13:20:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-03-05 13:20:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-03-05 13:20:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-03-05T13:20:21.662023Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) initializing of server in progress as process 42
2021-03-05T13:20:21.675007Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-05T13:20:22.643221Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-05T13:20:24.871463Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-03-05 13:20:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-03-05 13:20:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-03-05T13:20:29.854747Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 87
2021-03-05T13:20:29.882866Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-05T13:20:30.177247Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-05T13:20:30.340904Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-05T13:20:30.477364Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-05T13:20:30.477747Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-05T13:20:30.482566Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-03-05T13:20:30.505587Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-03-05 13:20:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2021-03-05 13:20:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database thesis
2021-03-05 13:20:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user admindev
2021-03-05 13:20:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user admindev access to schema thesis

2021-03-05 13:20:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2021-03-05T13:20:33.332383Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.23).
2021-03-05T13:20:35.763423Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-03-05 13:20:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2021-03-05 13:20:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2021-03-05T13:20:36.568558Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 1
2021-03-05T13:20:36.580255Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-03-05T13:20:36.776157Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-03-05T13:20:36.885922Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-03-05T13:20:36.950707Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-03-05T13:20:36.950893Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-03-05T13:20:36.956239Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-03-05T13:20:36.971274Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

myapi container logs:

```
2021-03-05 13:23:09.481  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2021-03-05 13:23:09.566  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 74ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-05 13:23:10.186  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@2eee3069' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-03-05 13:23:10.194  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-03-05 13:23:10.714  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2021-03-05 13:23:10.732  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-05 13:23:10.732  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2021-03-05 13:23:10.828  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-05 13:23:10.828  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2738 ms
2021-03-05 13:23:11.152  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-05 13:23:11.222  INFO 1 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-05 13:23:11.289  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-05 13:23:11.320  INFO 1 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2021-03-05 13:23:11.606  INFO 1 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-03-05 13:23:11.782  INFO 1 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-05 13:23:12.386  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5649ec46, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3e598df9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7f9e1534, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@78dc4696, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@79b663b3, stefan.buciu.config.filter.AuthenticationFilter@502f8b57, stefan.buciu.config.filter.AuthorizationFilter@5652f555, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@99a65d3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6813a331, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4fe01805, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@81ff872, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5f8890c2]
2021-03-05 13:23:13.038 ERROR 1 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar!/:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: admindev
    password: admindev
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
server:
  port: 5000
  servlet:
    contextPath: /api
```

I also thought of attaching the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./target/*.jar /home/app/application.jar

WORKDIR /home/app

CMD ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

In the `COPY` command I used a star because there is only one *.jar produce by maven, and I didn't want to always change my Dockerfile when I change my version. That command works if there is only one file.

The artefacts are built using `mvn package` and I had no errors there, if I run myself the command: `java -jar *.jar` in the target dir, the server starts running without any problems.

Comment: actually I don't know what is wrong here, it works for me with a sample Spring Boot app and Dockerfile from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/. the only issue was that first time, myapi started before mysql started, so myapi died. but the next time, mysql started quite soon, so myapi started all fine. you might want to look into ordering, otherwise this config is fine

Comment: you can use docker logs -f mysql command to see crashing container logs and maybe you can find the problem

Comment: IsaToltar I looked into the logs and I didn't really find anything useful, I also attached them in the post.

62mkv I will try to use that docker file, but atm I have my own Dockerfile.

Comment: @62mkv OMG you were right, I just pressed start twice and it started running. By why does it fail the first time? I use `depends_on: mysql`. Shouldn't it be synchronized behind the scenes?

Comment: @vivere well, according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/: However, for startup Compose does not wait until a container is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running. ... Use a tool such as wait-for-it, dockerize, sh-compatible wait-for, or RelayAndContainers template. These are small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections.

Comment: @62mkv According to this:https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#short-syntax-1, having `depends_on: myService: condition: service_completed_successfully` should be okay

Comment: report an issue to docker then, if it's not working as per documentation

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. So thanks to you, I managed to fix my issue by restarting. After that, you provided me with the info that depending on a service doesn't necessarily mean that the service in question is ready to be used and meanwhile I looked into this myself and found their documentation on this. Using it with the condition works as expected, so now everything is good. I just wanted to share with you the info, but probably in the context you thought that it doesn't work. Everything is good now on my side